# Error: Writing tests in Python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a automation test using selenium and python webdriver

```
 class UserAccountsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()

    def testFirstUser(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        driver.get('website.com')
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

My error:
**object has no attribute 'driver'**
Im not sure why I can't assign driver to self.driver. Am I passing in self correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your `setup()` function `setUp()` as described in [unittest wiki](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html).

> Luckily, we can factor out such set-up code by implementing a method
>   called setUp(), which the testing framework will automatically call
>   for us when we run the test